# Use of Maven publish plugin for Android project in Gradle 5

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a script to publish APK artifacts to Nexus using the "maven-publish" plugin.
In Gradle 4 it was possible to have a configuration like this (this works):

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://$MY_NEXUS_SERVER$/repository/${project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? 'snapshots' : 'releases'}"
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
        publications {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    if (variant.name == "release") {
                        create("apk${variant.name.capitalize()}", MavenPublication) {
                            groupId project.group
                            artifactId project.name
                            version project.version

                            artifact(output.outputFile)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Gradle 5 [this is no longer possible](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:deferred_configuration)

When trying to build the project I get this error:

```
Cannot create a Publication named 'android' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Publication to create. Known subtypes are: MavenPublication
```

**How can I rewrite this code to be compatible with Gradle 5?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works (equivalent to my code example above):

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://$MY_NEXUS_SERVER$/repository/${project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? 'snapshots' : 'releases'}"
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
        publications {
            create("apkRELEASE", MavenPublication) {
                afterEvaluate {
                    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                        variant.outputs.each { output ->
                            if (variant.name == "release") {
                                groupId project.group
                                artifactId project.name
                                version project.version

                                artifact(output.outputFile)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems like wrapping into a `afterEvaluate`-block does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for building arbitrary variants (tested on Gradle 5.5.1 / Android Gradle 3.5.0):

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://$MY_NEXUS_SERVER$/repository/${project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') ? 'snapshots' : 'releases'}"
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
        publications {
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    "maven${variant.name.capitalize()}Apk"(MavenPublication) {
                        groupId project.group
                        artifactId project.name
                        version project.version

                        artifact(output.outputFile)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of resulting publish task when building with debug variant: `publishMavenDebugApkPublicationToMavenRepository`